# Is there an API Style reference for Visual Studio Macros

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-macros

I would like to automate some common tasks that I do using Visual Studio Macros but I can't find a decent API reference for visual studio objects accessible through macros.

Does such a think exist?

Or is there a way I can find out what I need with the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the [DTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.macros.dte.aspx)?

[Extending the Visual Studio Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esk3eey8.aspx)

[Customizing, Automating, and Extending the Development Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae3cxw0w.aspx)

[How to: Use Add-ins to Control Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xw5w769.aspx)

Comment: That was what I was after thanks.  MSDN is a bloody huge maze