# Visual Studio 2015/ReSharper keyboard shortcut for unquoting text

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, macros, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

With *VIM*, I can use Tim Pope's wonderful *vim-surround* plugin to place the cursor within a string and issue the `ds"` keyboard sequence in order to unquote it. How can an equivalent be achieved in *VS* natively or with *Resharper*?

- *VIM* + *vim-surround*:

  `"aaa|aaaaa"` ---> press `ds"` ---> `aaa|aaaaa`
- In *VS*, I know I can use a regex Find/Replace query with:

  `|"aaaaaaaa"` ---> press `Ctrl+H` ---> ...

  **Find**: `"(.+?)"|'(.+?)'`
  **Replace** with: `$1`

  ... press `Alt+R` to replace next, and we have:
  `aaaaaaaa`
  (the next matching quoted string is selected)

... but I'd like to turn it into a macro triggered by a keyboard shortcut.

I installed the *Macros for Visual Studio* extension from the *Visual Studio Gallery*, but this doesn't register interactions with the Find/Replace dialogue when recording a macro.

I tried writing a Macro myself based on [Using Search and Replace Macros in Visual Studio](https://mleeb.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/quicktip-using-search-and-replace-macros-in-visual-studio/), but it doesn't work. I'm getting errors that e.g. `vsFindTarget` and `vsFindPatternSyntax.vsFindPatternSyntaxRegExpr` are not defined.

Here's my failed macro code:

```
dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Replace");

dte.Find.FindWhat = "\"(.+?)\"|'(.+?)'";
dte.Find.ReplaceWith = "$1"
dte.Find.Target = vsFindTarget.vsFindTargetCurrentDocument
dte.Find.PatternSyntax = vsFindPatternSyntax.vsFindPatternSyntaxRegExpr
dte.Find.ResultsLocation = vsFindResultsLocation.vsFindResultsNone
dte.Find.Action = vsFindAction.vsFindActionReplace
dte.Find.Execute()
```

I looked at [Microsoft's documentation mentioned in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4719410/4646649), but I'm getting issues as above. Makes me think that *Macros for Visual Studio extension* has it's own API on top of the native *VS* API, or (most likely) I'm just not getting it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: vsFindTarget class is in the EnvDTE namespace. You can try to access it like EnvDTE.vsFindTarget.vsFindTargetCurrentDocument.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work: 'EnvDTE' is undefined.

Comment: It seems some of the information I need is here: [How do I start developing VSIX extensions?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246938.aspx#BKMK_StartDeveloping) and here: [How do I set keyboard shortcuts in a VSPackage?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246938.aspx#Anchor_10). I'll post back if I figure it out.

Comment: I also found this: [How to: Automate Text Search and Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44de0117.aspx). I just have to put it all together.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much experience with Macros for Visual Studio extension. As an alternative to developing a vsix extension, you can run this macro with my Visual Commander.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Your _Visual Commander_ seems to be very cool. Too bad it doesn't have _IntelliSense_ support. I played around with it for a bit, and with more time, I'd probably figure it out. That said, for now, I went with the _Vim+VS_ integration (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled for integrating *Vim* with *Visual Studio* [using Vim as an external tool](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Integrate_gvim_with_Visual_Studio#Vim_as_an_external_tool), but with console *Vim* rather than *gVim*:

1. In *VS*, go to **Tools** > **External Tools...** > **Add**

   - **Title**: `&Vim`
   - **Command**: `C:\[...]\usr\bin\mintty.exe` (or wherever you have `mintty.exe` - e.g. it's part of the *Git for Windows* installation)
   - **Arguments**: `"C:\[...]\usr\bin\vim.exe" +"call cursor($(CurLine),$(CurCol))" +"runtime visualstudioinvoke.vim" "$(ItemFileName)$(ItemExt)"` (use the actual path to your `vim.exe`; a very long path might not work)
   - **Initial directory**: `$(ItemDir)`
   - Optionally, set the tool as the first one, for convenience (see point 4)
   - Click **OK**
2. Create `~/.vim/visualstudioinvoke.vim` or `~/vimfiles/visualstudioinvoke.vim` depending on whichever works (for me, the former did) with the following contents:

```
    set autoread
    autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * call CheckTime()

    " How many seconds to wait between file timestamp checks
    let s:check_time_delay=5
    let s:last_check_time=reltime()

    function CheckTime()
      if(reltime(s:last_check_time)[0] > s:check_time_delay)
        let s:last_check_time=reltime()
        checktime %
      endif
    endfunction
```

The above makes sure *Vim* automatically reloads the file if it's been changed in *VS* (or anywhere else outside of *Vim*). The check happens on cursor move within *Vim*, but not more often than every 5 seconds.

3. Back in *VS*, go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Environment** > **Documents** and thick `Detect when file is changed outside the environment` and `Reload modified files unless there are unsaved changes`
4. Add a keyboard shortcut for the *Vim* external tool in *VS*:

   - Go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Environment** > **Keyboard** and **Show commands containing**: `Tools.ExternalCommand1` (assuming *Vim* is the first external tool).
   - Under **Press shortcut keys**, I used the **[Ctrl]**+**[`]** (backtick) combo; use whatever you like.

That's it. Now you can quickly open in *Vim* the file you're looking at in *VS* and the cursor position is preserved. Also the saved changes are synchronised automatically between the editors. For the text unquoting, make sure you have [vim-surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) in your *Vim*.

Comment: I have now used this for 10 days and it works like a charm. One thing I have changed is the key combination to start _Vim_. Now it's **[Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Shift]+[v]** and it doesn't seem to clash with anything. Since I received no other complete answers, I accept this as the chosen solution.